# preservation of localness among certain Krull domains

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a local Krull domain, and let $\mathfrak p$ be a height one prime ideal whose class in the divisor class group is non-torsion.  (That is, $\mathfrak p^{(n)}$ is non-principal for all $n$.)  Obviously, this limits what $R$ can be -- e.g. it can't be one-dimensional.  Let $$
S := \bigcap_{\mathfrak q \in Spec R, \text{ht}(\mathfrak q)=1, \mathfrak q \neq \mathfrak p} R_{\mathfrak q}
$$
Is $S$ local?  And if not, is $\mathfrak p S$ a proper ideal of $S$?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181036/preservation-of-localness-among-certain-krull-domains